# Download a file from sas token

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created a `storage_account` with a `container` named **data**.
In that container I have a single .zip file.

I'm generating an Account Key SAS Token with Read permission directly on the  data `container` :

[image]

The Blob SAS URL looks like this :

`https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/data?sp=r&st=2022-06-06T15:23:31Z&se=2022-06-06T23:23:31Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=<SIGNATURE>`

How am I supposed to download my zip file from that URI?

I'm always running into some **Authorization error** whereas I though having the link was enough and unfortunately documentation didn't help me to figure out what's wrong.

I would like to download the file from a HTTP call, not using `az copy` or `powershell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your description and the URL you provided, I guess the issue is that you didn't reference the name of the zip file in the URL

so instead of

```
https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/data?sp=r&st=2022-06-06T15:23:31Z&se=2022-06-06T23:23:31Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=<SIGNATURE>
```

try

```
https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/data/zipName?sp=r&st=2022-06-06T15:23:31Z&se=2022-06-06T23:23:31Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=<SIGNATURE>
```

Comment: I can't believe that was just that ahah. Thanks !

Comment: Happy to help, if you find my answer useful, vote it up, so other people can find it easily